# fancybox and wordpress: image titles

Tags: jquery, wordpress, fancybox, fancybox-2

I've got fancybox working well with wordpress without a plugin but am struggling with the image titles.

fancybox is looking in the anchor for the title but wordpress puts the title in the img.

I've looked at all the workarounds and tried every stackoverflow solution but nothing seems to work.

I think there are two options:
1. Tell fancybox to use the img title (or alt) instead of the anchor title
2. Run a function to extract the attachment title and insert it into the anchor

There are plenty of solutions around but I'm obviously doing something wrong.

Any suggestions?

Comment: go with the 1st one tell fancybox to use image alt tags :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either get the value of the `alt` or `title` attributes in the `<img>` tag using the `beforeShow` fancybox's callback like :

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    beforeShow: function () {
        // option 1
        // get the title from "alt" attribute
        this.title = $(this.element).find("img").attr("alt");
        // option 2
        // get the title from "title" attribute in img tag
        // this.title = $(this.element).find("img").attr("title");
    }
});
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/9jqwf/)**

Comment: Thanks JFK, I'd seen this answer on another forum but just couldn't get it to work. The problem seems to be if I use helper with the beforeshow callback. Adding:`helpers:  {
        title : {
            type : 'inside'
        }    }` and the title no longer displays

Comment: @fisicx : it does work, check **[updated JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/9jqwf/1/)**. Most likely you forgot to separate the options with a comma `,`

Comment: Yup that was the problem. Thanks